# add File, Function, Line to global boost logger

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I have working boost log code, but want to append File, Function, and Line to every log call.  Here is my code:

logging.hpp

```
#ifndef LOGGING_HPP
#define LOGGING_HPP

#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>

#define INFO  BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::info)
#define WARN  BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::warning)
#define ERROR BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::error)

#define SYS_LOGFILE "/var/www/html/logs/pal5.log"

//Narrow-char thread-safe logger.
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger_t;

//declares a global logger with a custom initialization
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, logger_t)

#endif
```

logging.cpp

```
#include "../include/logging.hpp"

// CFLAGS += -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
// LIBS += -lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lpthread

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

//Defines a global logger initialization routine
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(my_logger, logger_t)
{
    logger_t lg;

    logging::add_common_attributes();

    logging::add_file_log(
            keywords::file_name = SYS_LOGFILE,
            keywords::rotation_size = 1024 * 1024 * 20,    // megabytes
            keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point (0, 0, 0),
            keywords::auto_flush = true,
            keywords::format = (
                    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time <boost::posix_time::ptime> ("TimeStamp", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    << " [" << expr::attr <boost::log::trivial::severity_level> ("Severity") << "]: "
                    << expr::smessage
            )
    );

    logging::add_console_log(
            std::cout,
            keywords::format = (
                    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time <boost::posix_time::ptime> ("TimeStamp", "%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
                    << " [" << expr::attr <boost::log::trivial::severity_level> ("Severity") << "]: "
                    << expr::smessage
            )
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );

    return lg;
}
```

Here is how I currently call it:

```
INFO << __FILE__ << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << ") | started";
```

Is it possible to automate this with global defines?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define your macros as

```
#define INFO  BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::info) << __FILE__ << "(" ..
```

Comment: whoops, I tried that, but I guess I didn't recompile with the header properly; thanks

Answer (score 1):

My updated `logging.hpp` four years later to show just the filename without the path to it:

```
#ifndef LOGGING_HPP
#define LOGGING_HPP

#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>

#define __FILENAME__ (__builtin_strrchr(__FILE__, '/') ? __builtin_strrchr(__FILE__, '/') + 1 : __FILE__)
#define TRACE BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::trace) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "
#define DEBUG BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::debug) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "
#define INFO BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::info) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "
#define WARNING BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::warning) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "
#define ERROR BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::error) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "
#define FATAL BOOST_LOG_SEV(my_logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::fatal) << "[" << __FILENAME__ << "/" << __FUNCTION__ << ":" << __LINE__ << "] "

#define SYS_LOGFILE "/var/www/html/logs/pal5_%y-%m-%d_#%N.log"

//Narrow-char thread-safe logger.
typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger_t;

//declares a global logger with a custom initialization
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, logger_t)

#endif
```